# How do I change the values that get affected by nudge_y?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a waterfall chart that looks roughly like this.

[image]

I'd like to nudge the labels on the green bars up by .1% and nudge the labels on the red bars down by .1%. I've tried to wrap `nudge_y` in an `aes()` but it serves me an error.

Is there a way to use an ifelse statement or apply a nudge to just a subset of values?

Comment: I'm not sure. Alternatively, you could use `geom_text(aes(y = your_y_variable * 1.1))` to get a similar effect. Or `geom_text(aes(y = your_y_variable + sign(your_y_variable) * 0.01))`.

Comment: That solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just re-posting my comment as an answer so this doesn't show up as unanswered and for future people with similar questions.

I don't know about nudging subsets of your data, however from what you say you are trying to achieve I think that the following may help.

For a proportional nudge to the text:

```
geom_text(aes(y = your_y_variable * 1.1))
```

For an absolute nudge to the text:

```
geom_text(aes(y = your_y_variable + sign(your_y_variable) * 0.01))
```